# python gdal_polygonize error

Tags: python, gdal

I am trying to use gdal_polygonize to create a polygon from a binary raster.

My code is:

```
os.system('gdal_polygonize.py ' + filename + ' -f ESRI Shapefile ' + shapefile)
```

where filename is a string file path with a '.tif' extension and 'shapefile' has a .shp

I am receiving the following error message:

```
Creating output Shapefile of format ESRI.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gdal_polygonize.py", line 164, in <module>
    dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource( dst_filename )
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateDataSource'
```

I have browsed the internet for help but to no avail. I am running the programme from NXclient on a windows 7 machine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Becky

Comment: Try directly the command `gdal_polygonize.py my_tif.tif -f "ESRI Shapefile" my_shapefile.shp` to be sure that the os.system call is not the problem. You also forgot the double quotes for "ESRI Shapefile"

Comment: Thanks for that - The problem was solved simply by putting in the quotation marks in : "ESRI Shapefile"

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I didn't use quotation marks when specifying output format: "ESRI Shapefile"